# Webapp that merges, filters and sorts chronologically a large number of RSS feeds

Tags: web-apps, rss

I got a set of about 150 RSS feeds I need to sort, filter and then refeed in a stream organized in chronological order.

I've been using chimpfeedr and rssmix to gather the feeds, sending them to IFTTT to add specific tags, then I capture that stream and manually sort and filter the first 50 entries each day and delete the rest (my crude version of chronological order).  There must be another way to do this, *right*?

I've been searching for several weeks.  I looked on github and see several filters, but do not see one that would create an outbound feed or provide all the filtering I need. Maybe I am just looking in the wrong place.  I've got a feeling the solution will cause me to slap my forehead and declare myself an idiot.

Want to be able to grab all tags (author, title, description, pubdate etc) in XML formatted feeds and eliminate fields with no data.  Also would be great to be able to add content such as a link to our news page in addition to the RSS link to the original story.

Answer (score 1):

You could try feed reader with filtering and ability to export folder as feed: BazQux Reader (I'm developer), InoReader or perhaps TT-RSS if you want to self-host the reader.

Comment: Than you for the suggestions, I looked at each.  I am not looking for reader.  I am looking for website or app that will take multiple feeds, delete those older than 24 hours, filter for keywords and sort (newest first) them and send the result out in a consolidated RSS feed.  I would use this to feed the "today's news" widget on our webpage.

Comment: just read your answer more closely, I also want to AUTOMATE this process, not to have it require manual processing.

Answer (score 1):

RSS automation used to be a breeze when [Yahoo! Pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo_Pipes) were still alive (that was long ago when Yahoo was still a going concern).

Nowadays, you are left with some Python magic, namely [riko](https://github.com/nerevu/riko) - a F/LOSS library that glues RSS processing together (and I probably must state that I'm not related to its author). Please note that RSS/Atom feeds are tricky and advertized item dates do not always correspond to *ground truth*. For instance, there are feeds that set dates in the future, or on January 1, 1970.

Since you haven't named **riko** in your question, I assume you haven't seen it. If you have evaluated it, I apologize for wasting your time; feel free to downvote my answer.

Comment: Not a python guy, really no coding skills, but I loaded WinPython and downloaded the Riko Git.  Not sure I am running it right, but it does not appear to provide a user interface to set the search and filter paramerters, so this is probably not my solution.

Comment: AND  -- I truly do miss Yahoo Pipes, that was how ran this feed for the longest time.  It was simple, clean, easy to edit.  It pulled feeds, soredt, filtered and sent out a custom RSS feed.  Is there no one-for-one exact duplicate out there to Pipes? Been looking for more than a year and not seen anything.
We might hire someone to solve this.  We need a user interface that let’s us create edit/manage custom filters and sorting.  Any recommendations on that?
Want to thank @nicolas-raoul for putting us in the right forum.